# How to upload to Arduino STM32 with HC-05 Serial Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, upload, serial-port

I got myself a little STM32F103C8T6 based board that is similar in size to the Arduino Nano, but with a little bit more memory and speed. But for me more important, with 3.3V I/O. It can also be used with the Arduino IDE after you install the correct libraries.

I wanted to connect this to a HC-05 serial bluetooth, especially for remote uploading. But this didn't work. Basic transfer worked, but upload for reprogramming failed.

I tried to adjust the baudrate with AT-commands of the HC-05: e.g.:

```
AT+UART=57600,0,0
```

But it still didn't work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After several tests I noticed that stm32flash printed "8e1" as upload setting. This means even parity. So the correct AT-command should be:

```
AT+UART=57600,0,2
```

Baudrates 115200 and 230400 also worked as long as the parity is correct.

But since there are even more things that can go wrong, here is some more information:

Connecting via bluetooth to the HC-05 required using the default password "1234". (This can later be changed with command "AT+PSWD=....".)

Then on my Windows 10 machine two new COM-ports appeared, of which only one was functional.

**The most confusing thing was that on Windows you still can adjust the baud rate and serial settings, but it has no effect!**

To use the AT-commands I had to connect to another serial port (from an USB to serial adapter). Holding the "Key"-button during power-on enables the AT-mode with 38400 baud.

There is a video that shows the details for a regular Arduino:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXUKfTNHkKE
"HC 05 Bluetooth Wireless Upload to Arduino" (Wayne Holder)

Even with the correct baud settings, remember to put the STM32 board into correct boot mode and press RESET. And use the correct COM-port.

If you use the serial port in your uploaded program you also must remember to use these settings. E.g.:

```
Serial.begin(57600,SERIAL_8E1); // for serial init
```